# Excel freezes when copying a few cells multiple times

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, freeze, microsoft-excel-2013

I have had a frequent problem in Excel 2013 and Excel 2010 on several different computers, where Excel would freeze for 10-20 seconds when I copied a few cells into 3 or more locations.

I frequently want to copy data into every other row, so I end up hitting paste repeatedly on the same set of copied data, until Excel freezes and I have to wait for it.

I'm hoping someone else has encountered this same problem and has a workaround or solution for this, as when I have to fill in a hundred columns of data this really slows me down.

I've had this problem on three different computers, in both Office Excel 2013 and Office Excel 2010, so it doesn't seem specific to any particular computer setup.

I've attached an example where Excel froze during a copy, and a list of my addins installed.

[image: addins]
[image: copy example.]

Comment: In order to resolve this on your own, what have you tried or researched? Are you using multiple select when pasting? Or one row at a time? Is the clipboard open while doing this (where you can see the copied objects listed)?

Comment: I'm pasting one row at a time.
I've found the same error pasting data in other excel documents as well. Whenever I do several copy / pastes in a row (or copy paste paste paste) it seems to happen

Comment: Also, I just tested this issue on my coworker's desk and got the same thing to happen.

Comment: I've removed all of my addins and the problem still happens.

Comment: I curious if it happens if you do a multiple select (CTRL + click) all the cells where you want to paste, then paste.

Comment: It doesn't freeze if I multipaste.

Comment: Maybe it's the repeated calls from the clipboard that are freezing it. I will enter as an answer, so it you think that it solved it you can choose it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using paste from the clipboard repeatedly may cause performance lag or freezing. To avoid this, use multiple select (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd>) to choose all the cells you want the content in, then paste.

Here is additional information which might be helpful as well - [What can cause slow copy and paste in Excel?](http://blogs.technet.com/b/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/archive/2011/09/08/what-can-cause-slow-copy-and-paste-in-excel.aspx)

If the problem continues or gets worse, I'd suggest a repair install of Office.

Answer (score 1):

That is possible if you work with a large workbook and the Calculation setting is set to Automatic. 
Please try to temporarily switch to the manual mode (Options->formulas-> workbook calculation -> manual) and paste again.

If it doesn’t help, you need to define if the cause of the issue is the workbook or Excel/PC. 
Try to copy and paste in a new workbook. If it works, look into the problematic book – VBA macro, many conditional formatting rules, links to other workbooks...

Comment: I might just do this. There's no calculations in this worksheet anyway, its just for data entry.

Comment: Even with Calculation set to manual, it still freezes.

Answer (score 1):

I tried 20 suggested solutions from all types of forums, but none worked.

Then it occurred to me that the only "treatment" these cells had was "Conditional Formatting"

I cleared the conditions (Conditional Formatting / Clear Rules / Clear Rules from Selected Cells) and it worked. I even reinstated the original rule and it still works :)